# Can we keep color code the same across the dashboard?

Tags: reporting, picklist, dashboard

We use data.com clean dashboard to track our data integrity.
One issue that is disturbing is that values, for the same field, are colored differently across the dashbaord.
The field, is the CleanStatus, standard field.

[image]

How can I keep the color the same across the different reports? and across the dashboard?

/// CleanStatus field under 'Account' Object
[image]

Comment: Is CleanStatus is accessible under object details & is it a picklist?

Comment: thanks for asking, yes, CleanStatus is available under all 3 objects (screenshot added for account object)